# Use DHCP server from local network for guest system

Tags: linux, virtualization, dhcp, qemu, pxe

I have a host system connected to with `eth0` interface to the local network. Host system get network config from DHCP server that runs in this local network.

I want to test PXE related configuration of my DHCP server using guest system that I run using qemu:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 \
        -nodefaults \
        -nographic \
        -serial stdio \
        -boot once=n
```

How can I config network on host and guest so DHCP request that run PXE client in guest system will go the DHCP server in the local network and return back to the guest system?

Comment: A bridge**d** setup.

Comment: Yes, I understand it. But how exactly? I do not want to broke network on host. If I just create new bridge with `eth0` and tap interface I get from qemu network on host just breaking down.

Comment: Well, sounds like you had some experience and the problem may be the fact that you didn't know the IP configuations on the host should be done on the bridge instead of `eth0` then (how to modify really depends on what you use to manage your networking on the host)